# How can I showoff my ASP.NET application to my friends?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-development-serv

So, I made a cool demo which I want to show to my friends. But when I give them my IP-address (with the Development server's port and aspx page), it doesn't connect. How can I make it work?

Comment: We would definitely need more info. Are you getting a 404? 403? Is your computer firewalled? Have you forwarded the proper ports? etc.

Comment: He just said that he's running the site on VS's dev server; what more info do you need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They can't see the development server port.
It only serves pages to browser requests on the local computer.

You have to publish it to your IIS or to another machine that has IIS.

Comment: In case someone wonders, installing the IIS and other useful components is very easy using the Web platform installer 2.0 http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Deploy your site to your Local IIS server

Comment: Could you kindly point me to the minimal IIS install package I would need to deploy on my Windows 7?

Comment: in add/remove windows features you can install IIS, from there you will have to add a rule to your firewall to allow access to port 80, and then you will have to create an application in IIS and point it to the project folder

Answer (score 1):

The development server will only server connections from localhost.  You need to deploy it to a real IIS server instance.  Since you don't likely have Windows Server lying around, you can install IIS on any *Professional* edition of windows.  Then your site will run on port 80, just like any other web site.  You still may also need to forward that port on your home router.

Answer (score 0):

Cassini (developers web server) has limitations and doesn't serve http requests from intranet/internet

You should deploy your site to IIS on your workstation (if your friends observe workstation via IP) or use Internet Asp.net Hosting

Answer (score 0):

The development server can only be accessed by clients on the local box.  You'll need to host your site on IIS to let them access it (assuming they're on your local network.)  If you need to expose this on the internet, you'll have to get a hosting company to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the built-in webserver called cassini. By default, that webserver does only accept request from the localhost.

Set up a local IIS, and forward all necessary ports through the firewall

Answer (score 0):

You should find a reliable and already configured webhost and host your site there.  The first hit on google for "free asp.net host" was [here](http://www.aspspider.com/).